# Mexico Spanish Not Available in 19.10

Tags: system-language

How can I install Mexican Spanish to Ubuntu (GNOME) 19.10?
There seems to be only one regional version of Spanish (Spain) in Ubuntu 19.10.

Is this going to be a thing moving forward?
Is there another way of installing Mexican Spanish besides the Region & Languages GUI menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://discourse.gnome.org/t/tu-usted-in-spanish-translations/748 discusses how GNOME, the desktop environment of standard Ubuntu, only has one version of Spanish.

This may be different with the other 'flavours' of Ubuntu, [listed here,](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) because they use different desktops other than GNOME. Linux does allow for [dialectical variations of Spanish](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#The-LANGUAGE-variable) (not surprising, as there are more dialects of Spanish than any other major language).

You may wish to consider loading other flavours onto a LiveUSB, and trying them to see which has superior support for Mexican Spanish.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have Ubuntu (GNOME) 18.04.3 on a desktop that gives me the option of Mexican Spanish, which is why I found it baffling that when I installed the newest version on my laptop it did not give me that option.